# Application/pdf data starts download instead of viewing it

Tags: java, google-chrome, pdf, web

I have web-application. 
When I follow a link:
http://..... document/view?type=pdf
I expect browser to show a pdf file. It works correct on Firefox and IE, but Chrome starts downloading it instead of showing.

Here is the code:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test;");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(pdfByteData);
out.flush();
```

What could be the problem? May be it is because of my local chrome settings or something else? I have no idea.

Comment: have you tried also adding an extension to the PDF filename? response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf;");

Comment: Yep, nothing changes, Chrome downloads the file :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the pdf plugin in chrome using the following link

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142056?hl=en

> **How Browsers Work With File Downloads**
>
> Usually when a user goes to a file URL (for example: a download link), the file will show in the
>   browser if the browser supports it. Image files like jpg, png, gif
>   etc. will almost always show in the browser. Archive files like zip,
>   tar, gzip etc. will always be downloaded. Some file types show up in
>   some browsers but not others depending of if the browser can read the
>   file or not. For example, Internet Explorer (IE) will usually try to
>   show Microsoft Word files (doc and docx) in the browser, while most
>   other browsers will download it. Google Chrome has its own PDF
>   converter and it will try to convert a PDF file and render it in the
>   browser.
>
> The key thing to understand is that some browsers maybe able to read a
>   particular file type based on the addons you have installed for that
>   browser while others may not be able to. If a browser can read the
>   file type it will show it in the browser. If the browser cannot read a
>   file type it will force a download to the hard disk. Usually this is
>   not an issue since the users can save the file to there computer after
>   it is shown in the browser.

Comment: Doesnt matter. I added that line while looking for a solution. It is not changing the situation :(

Comment: @user2060247 Updated the resolution, you may need to install the pdf plugin in chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It really helped me! The problem was that I disabled build-in Chrome pdf-reader a few month ago. Thx!

Answer (score -1):

Just use HTML command, this what i did to my website :

`<a href="Sources/Your%20PDF%20File.pdf">Click Here to view the PDF file</a>`

works in every browser !.

Comment: The problem is I need to give an url to external system, so somebody follows it and sees the document. Mime type and the content depend on id. (It could be jpg for example or pdf, and I faced that problem with pdf)